# GCC does not throw warnings and compiles erroneous code

Tags: debian, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Enter your name\n");
  char name[99];
  scanf("%d", name);
  printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}
```

While executing this simple program I mistakenly used  `%d` instead of `%s`. But when I compiled the code using `gcc`, it didn't display any warnings. It simply created an output file.

```
$ gcc greet.c
$ ls
greet.c a.out
$
```

Whereas compiling this code with `clang` does display warnings. I am quite certain that `gcc` should have displayed warnings just like `clang` did without passing any arguments.
I recently switched from Ubuntu to Debian and I don't know if this is due to some missing dependency.

Some additional information

```
GCC version : gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0
OS : Debian 10(Buster)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On GCC, format string checks are controlled by [`-Wformat`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), which isn’t enabled by default.

Building your code with `-Wformat` (or `-Wall`, which includes it) does warn:

```
$ gcc -Wformat    630368.c   -o 630368
630368.c: In function ‘main’:
630368.c:6:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
        scanf("%d", name);
               ~^   ~~~~
               %hhd
```

(with GCC 8), or

```
$ gcc -Wformat    630368.c   -o 630368
630368.c: In function ‘main’:
630368.c:6:16: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
    6 |        scanf("%d", name);
      |               ~^   ~~~~
      |                |   |
      |                |   char *
      |                int *
      |               %hhd
```

(with GCC 10).

Ubuntu ships GCC with custom specs which enable `-Wformat` by default; see `gcc -dumpspecs`:

```
*distro_defaults:
%{!fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables:-fasynchronous-unwind-tables} %{!fno-stack-protector:%{!fstack-protector-all:%{!ffreestanding:%{!nostdlib:%{!fstack-protector:-fstack-protector-strong}}}}} %{!Wformat:%{!Wformat=2:%{!Wformat=0:%{!Wall:-Wformat} %{!Wno-format-security:-Wformat-security}}}} %{!fno-stack-clash-protection:-fstack-clash-protection} %{!fcf-protection*:%{!fno-cf-protection:-fcf-protection}}
```

(in particular `%{!Wformat:%{!Wformat=2:%{!Wformat=0:%{!Wall:-Wformat} %{!Wno-format-security:-Wformat-security}}}}`).

Comment: Is there a way to add those dumpspecs in Debian as well?

Comment: You can copy the Ubuntu specs to a file, and tell `gcc` to use that with `-specs=/path/to/ubuntu.specs`, but that’s no easier than specifying `-Wall` or `-Wformat`. To change the default specs, you’d have to rebuild the GCC packages. Alternatively, `export CFLAGS=-Wall CXXFLAGS=-Wall` and always build with `make`’s built-in rules...

Comment: _"Is there a way to add those dumpspecs in Debian as well?"_ - I would recommend that you don't; the default for gcc (almost everywhere) is very few warnings. You should use `-Wall` in your build procedure, to ensure the warnings are enabled, even if you reinstall, move distros, build your code on another computer, give someone else your code, etc. Also `-Wall` doesn't just enable these format warnings, it also enables many other essential warnings. Basically, with gcc (and most other C compilers), I consider `-Wall` non-optional. Or even `-Werror`.

Comment: You can just put it in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/specs` if you want it used by default (though distributions frown upon touching files there). But yes, as a developer, you should always use -Wall (possibly minus a few bad ones).

Comment: @StephenKitt debian does not ship a specs file, the default settings are hardcoded in the binary, so it is rather unlikely that your file would be overwritten. I would be more scared of adding broken specs, that prevent dkms from building kernel modules properly next time the kernel is updated. For that, a script `~/bin/gcc` which calls gcc with your favorite options seems much safer, since it is only used by this user.

Comment: @MarcGlisse ah yes, good point, the file wouldn’t be overwritten... The `~/bin/gcc` idea does seem like a better one.